# Comparing strings in perl

Tags: string, perl, if-statement

I have a perl code to compare 2 strings

First string I get from parsing a URL content (say $version and its value is CVP-LATEST-5.3.4.iso)

Another string I open a local file (info.txt) and read it. The file has only 1 string (say $oldversion and its value is CVP-LATEST-5.3.4.iso)

I get these both strings into  $version and $oldversion

after that I do

```
if ($version ne $oldversion)
{
print "Im doing something here\n");
unlink(info.txt);
open file info.txt
print $version to into.txt
close info.txt
}
else
{
print "ERROR\n");
}
```

Here you can see if $version and $oldversion match it will print ERROR.
Everything works fine until:

When I open the file info.txt and manually edit (I will press backspace and then will type the same charectores again) and then save and exit.

Even now $version and $oldversion should have the same content, because I pressed backspace and later entered the same deleted charector.

Now when I run the script  I can see the IF loop is going TRUE instead of FALSE. 
Since the contents are same the IF should go FALSE, But its going true.

I have no idea what is happening. I tried printing $version and $oldversion before and after the IF statement, it prints same exact same values, but IF is going TRUE. 
I read the file content as folows.

```
my $oldversion = <FILE>;
```

Comment: How are you reading from the file?  Maybe there is a trailing newline on $oldversion or $version.

Comment: yes, I just obseved a trailing newline in the content of the file. How do I read without that new line ?

Comment: You don't need to unlink the file, just do `open` with the truncate operator `>` to overwrite it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
my $oldversion = <FILE>;
chomp($oldversion);
```

Comment: thanks.. :) But will it remove the "o" when the program writes to the file and reads from it ?

Comment: @mac -- chomp() only alters trailing newlines (or more accurately, whatever is in $/)